# Is there any way to get the SHA of a commit from its message?

Tags: git

When doing a `git tag`, I'm not always great at remembering if HEAD~6 (for example) is inclusive or exclusive.

Given that most of my commits are prefixed with an issue number, I wondered if there is some magic command for searching for the commit SHA from part of its message.

*I know it's easy to do a `git log` and work from there, but I want more easy :)*

**EDIT** : Someone also asked the opposite question: [In Git, is there a way to get the “friendly” name for an arbitrary commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917102/in-git-is-there-a-way-to-get-the-friendly-name-for-an-arbitrary-commit)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `:/blah` syntax to specify a commit whose commit message starts with the given text.

E.g.

```
git show ":/Issue #299"
```

This is valid anywhere a commit can be used. E.g.

```
git cherry-pick ":/Issue #299"
```

If you actually need the SHA-1 of the commit you can just use rev-parse.

```
git rev-parse ":/Issue #299"
```

See the ["SPECIFYING REVISIONS" section of the git rev-parse man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html#_specifying_revisions):

> **A colon, followed by a slash, followed by a text**:
>   This names a commit whose commit message starts with the specified text.
>   This name returns the youngest matching commit which is reachable from any ref.
>   If the commit message starts with a `!`, you have to repeat that; the special sequence `:/!`, followed by something else than `!` is reserved for now.

Comment: @Benjol: IIRC, it finds the youngest reachable commit; you'll have to check the documentation.

Comment: Here's an updated URL that works: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#_specifying_revisions

Answer (score 9):

```
git log --grep=word
```

should help find the relevant commit.
(as opposed to searching for [commit *contents*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928584/how-to-grep-in-the-git-history), where git `log -S` (pickaxe option) or `git grep` are more appropriate)

Add various format options like

```
git log --grep=word --pretty=oneline
git log --grep=word --pretty=format:"%h"
```

(the last one displaying only the SHA1), and you are good to go.

---

See also "[Fun with `git log --grep`](http://gitster.livejournal.com/30195.html)"

```
git log --grep=frotz --grep=nitfol --since=1.month
```

> This finds the commits that happened within the last month and mentioned either frotz or nitfol in their commit log messages.
>   As with the usual "git grep", giving more than one patterns means "this or that".

The article points out that `git grep` is line oriented, and use the --all-match option in this `git log --grep` command.

> The way "`git log`" family uses the grep mechanism is exactly for this "does the whole thing has a match?" aspect , not "show me the lines that match these criteria" aspect.  It allows you to use this mechanism like so:

```
git log --all-match --grep=frotz --author=Linus
```

> This will show commits that mention frotz and written by Linus.

Comment: I was looking for something that I could pipe/use directly in another command, so if you add `--pretty=format:"%h"` to that, I'll mark you as the answer ;)

Comment: Adding --pretty=online to the command should improve readability even more.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I lied, @Charles Bailey got the tick :(

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
git rev-list --grep='message excerpt' HEAD
```

This will only list commits that are ancestors of `HEAD`. If you wanted to search all commits in the repository (including those that are not ancestors of `HEAD`), I'm not sure how to do that other than by manually going through all the branch heads manually and running this command. (There's probably a way, I just don't know what it might be)